# Redirect url with a hashcode to another with same hashcode in IIS10

Tags: web-config, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I need to redirect a url with a *variable* hashcode to another url with that *same hashcode* in IIS10 (Windows Server 2019).

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/hello/sd54effg1g5s11d5111dwds21fds2f1ffd
```

Needs to redirect to:

```
https://subdomain.example.com/hello/sd54effg1g5s11d5111dwds21fds2f1ffd
```

At the moment i have this as a rule in the web.config:

```
        <rule name="rulename" stopProcessing="true">

         <match url="^hello/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />

         <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(https:\/\/www\.)example.com$" />
         </conditions>        

        <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"  />

       </rule>
```

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: Updated the rule. Still not working but i think i'm getting close.

Comment: Nope. Still wrong pattern value in the condition part. If you want to match `www.example.com`, then it must be strictly `^www.example.com$`. You have to study some regular expression using a search engine.

Comment: Updated again. This should actually be easier ;-)

Comment: Actually, with www, it threw an error 500.

Comment: That's because you made another mistake by using `https://subdomain.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}`. Use hard coded `subdomain.example.com` instead of `subdomain.{HTTP_HOST}/`, and then try again. If you hit another issue, edit your question to include the actual error page. Merely saying "error 500" won't help anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `{HTTP_HOST}` is will not match the https part in the url. So you should use `^www.example.com$` instead of `^(https:\/\/www\.)example.com$`.

Besides, you should use `https://subdomain.example.com/{R:1}` instead of the `https://subdomain.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}` to achieve your requirement.

Details ,you could refer to below url rewrite rule:

```
    <rule name="rulename" stopProcessing="true">

     <match url="^hello/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />

     <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
     </conditions>        

    <action type="Redirect" url="https://subdomain.example.com/{R:0}"  />

   </rule>
```